# Print numbers from 1 to 100 and replace some with strings (fizzbuzz)

Tags: c#, fizzbuzz

I am trying the fizzbuzz program from here: [Why Can't Programmers.. Program?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/)

"Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz"."

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 5 == 0)
            {
                Response.Write("fizzbuzz" + ",");
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                Response.Write("fizz" + ",");
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                Response.Write("buzz" + ",");
            }
            else
            {
                i = i + 0;
            }

            Response.Write(i +",");
        }

    }
```

I am able to produce some kind of result like:

> 1,2,fizz,3,4,buzz,5,fizz,6,7,8,fizz,9,buzz,10,11,fizz,12,13,14,fizzbuzz,15,16,17,fizz,18,19,buzz,20,fizz,21,22,23,fizz,24,buzz,25,26,fizz,27,28,29,fizzbuzz,30,31,32,fizz,33,34,buzz,35,fizz,36,37,38,fizz,39, and so on..

The word **fizz** was printed but it did not replace 3 and **fizzbuzz** was printed but it did not replace 15 and so ...

Comment: Just a little improvement: remove first condition `if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 5 == 0)` and append comma only in the end of loop.

Comment: btw, what is `i = i + 0;` it for?! o_O

Comment: @zerkms - its not needed

Comment: O wait I see it floating on the left off this page?  CSS problem?

Comment: @zerkms : is there any easier method than what I have done ?

Comment: @nandu.com - I posted an edit for an `easier` way :).  See my edit

Comment: @zerkms : Nice, You reduced the code and got same output.. +1 for simple idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether you hit the if condition or not you are still printing `i` at the end of your code.

Look specifically at your for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)         
{             
if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 5 == 0)             
{                 
Response.Write("fizzbuzz" + ",");             
}             
else if (i % 3 == 0)             
{                 
Response.Write("fizz" + ",");             
}             
else if (i % 5 == 0)             
{                 
Response.Write("buzz" + ",");             
}             
else             
{                 
i = i + 0;             
}              
Response.Write(i +",");   //look here you print i
}
```

So you need to move that last Response.Write(i + ","); in the last `else` condition.  The **easiest** way to find bugs like these is to use the debugger and debug your program.  You will then easily see what the output is.  So definately use the debugger and set breakpoints / watches and watch what happens.  Your code should change to this:

```
  for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)         
    {             
    if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 5 == 0)             
    {                 
    Response.Write("fizzbuzz" + ",");             
    }             
    else if (i % 3 == 0)             
    {                 
    Response.Write("fizz" + ",");             
    }             
    else if (i % 5 == 0)             
    {                 
    Response.Write("buzz" + ",");             
    }             
    else             
    {                 
    Response.Write(i +",");   //look here you print i
    }              
    }
```

Notice the removal of `i=i+1` your `for` loop is handling this already by incrementing i.

### Edit

Not sure if this is easier but here is another way to do this using lambda's:

```
            List<int> t;
            t = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

            var fizzBuzz = t.Where(num => num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0);
            var fizz = t.Where(num => num % 3 == 0);
            var buzz = t.Where(num => num % 5 == 0);
            var notFizzBuzz = t.Where(num => num % 3 != 0 && num % 5 !=0);

            //print fizzBuzz elements
            Console.WriteLine("Printing fizzBuzz elements...");
            foreach (int i in fizzBuzz)
                Console.WriteLine(i);

            //print fizz elements
            Console.WriteLine("Printing fizz elements...");
            foreach (int i in fizz)
                Console.WriteLine(i);

            //print buzz elements
            Console.WriteLine("Printing buzz elements...");
            foreach (int i in buzz)
                Console.WriteLine(i);

            //print other elements
            Console.WriteLine("Printing all others...");
            foreach (int i in notFizzBuzz)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: so my code is almost correct, I just have to eliminate a line and move the correct inside else loop :).

Comment: @nandu.com in the edit I print the numbers rather then fizz / buzz / fizzbuzz, but you can modify that to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try these changes

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 5 == 0)
        {
            Response.Write("fizzbuzz" + ",");
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            Response.Write("fizz" + ",");
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            Response.Write("buzz" + ",");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(i +",");
        }           
    }
}
```

Your `i = i + 0` obviously does nothing, since you are adding 0 to the value of i.

And you are printing the number to the response regardless of the result of the if/else block (it's put after it), so it should be moved into else (meaning only print if the if, or else if did not match.

Answer (score 0):

move `Response.Write(i +",");` into your final else

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 5 == 0)
        {
            Response.Write("fizzbuzz" + ",");
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            Response.Write("fizz" + ",");
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            Response.Write("buzz" + ",");
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + 0; //this is totally useless
            Response.Write(i + ",");

        }

        //Response.Write(i +","); //This will always write the number, even if you wrote fizz or buzz
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple implementation of it:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((i % 3 == 0) ? ((i % 5 == 0) ? "FizzBuzz" : "Fizz") : ((i % 5 == 0) ? "Buzz" : i.ToString()));
        }
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void PrintMod3And5FromInterval(int start, int end)
    {
        if (end < start)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End number should be higher than start.");
        }
        else
        { 
            string result = "";
            for (int x = start; x <= end; x++)
            {
                if (x % 3 == 0)
                    result += "fizz";
                if (x % 5 == 0)
                    result += "buzz";
                if (result == "")
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                result = "";
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintMod3And5FromInterval(1, 100);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was my original solution...

```
for (let number = 1; number <= 100; number ++) {
if (number % 3 === 0 && number % 5 === 0) {
    console.log(number + "fizzbuzz");
} else if (number % 5 === 0) {
console.log(number + "buzz");
} else if (number % 3 === 0)
console.log(number + "fizz");
else  {
console.log(number);
}
}
```

But this one is much shorter...

```
for (let n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
  let output = "";
    if (n % 3 == 0) output += "Fizz";
    if (n % 5 == 0) output += "Buzz";
  console.log(output || n);
}
```